# Can someone identify the species of this frog/ toad?

Tags: species-identification, amphibians

Location: Tirupati, Andhra Pradesh, India

I found it at night time near a lake

It was quite small in size ( 5-6 cm Approx.) having dark brown spots all over its body and three prominent green stripes running along the length of its body and 2 stripes running across its upper body ( one crossing over its eyes).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like an **Indus Valley bullfrog (Hoplobatrachus tigerinus)**.
Your specimen would be a bit small, but the species is nocturnal, the area fits and the patterning looks like a decent match as well:

[image]
(taken from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoplobatrachus_tigerinus))